# RecyclerView Adapter invalidating objects

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I call 4 Asynctasks to the same URL in MainActivity (expecting to get the same results of each one)

```
sendRequest(WALKING);
sendRequest(WALKING);
sendRequest(WALKING);
sendRequest(WALKING);
```

With the result of the requests I create my Ruta object:

```
     Ruta ruta = new Ruta();
    ruta.distancia = new Distancia(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
    ruta.duracion = new Duracion(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
    ruta.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
    ruta.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
    ruta.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
    ruta.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
    ruta.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));
    ruta.tipo = mode;
    ruta.json = data;
    Log.d("objetofinal", ruta.tipo);
```

After creating the objects , I add them in my RecyclerView Adapter with this method which I call on MainActivity.

```
listRoutesAdapter.add(ruta);
```

The implementation of the method add in ListaRutasAdapter is this:

```
  //implementation
public void add(Ruta route) {
    listaRutas.add(route);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d("type_inserted", route.tipo);
}

//Resume of the adapter

public List<Ruta> listaRutas;

public ListaRutasAdapter(Context context, List<Ruta> listaRutas) {
    this.listaRutas = listaRutas;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public void deleteW(String modeN) {
    if (listaRutas != null && !listaRutas.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("Size of the list", String.valueOf(getItemCount()));
        for (int i = 0; i < listaRutas.size(); i++) {
            String modo = listaRutas.get(i).tipo;
            if (modo.equals(modeN)) {
                 listaRutas.remove(i);
                this.notifyItemRemoved(i);
                this.notifyItemRangeChanged(i, listaRutas.size());
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity i´m calling the method delete to remove all the items with certain type , in this case "walking".

```
listaRutasAdapter.deleteW("walking");
```

When i call the async tasks items i get correctly the 4 items drawn in the recyclerview:

[image]

But when i call the removeM method from my MainActivity it only removes 2 from my recyclerview .

Before I try to delete all the objects of the same type , I get the size of my list and it is always equal to the number of items that were not deleted . The comparison in `if (modo.equals(modeN))`is always false for those objects . And if I log the values of "modo" I get nothing .

Note : All the objects have exactly the same values for type , distance and time . Is not a bug or error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code as below

```
public void deleteW(String modeN) {

                if (listaRutas != null && !listaRutas.isEmpty()) {
                    int i = 0;
                        while (i < listaRutas.size() ) {      
                        String modo = listaRutas.get(i).tipo;
                        if (modo.equals(modeN)) {
                            listaRutas.remove(i);
                            i--;
                        }
                            i++;
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

Comment: It worked! But I still don´t understand the logic , can you explain the solution please ? Thanks !!!